# Firebase npm authentication error

Tags: node.js, authentication, firebase, google-oauth

I haven't touched my project in 2 weeks, but now when I tried running `npm start`, the server won't start, and I get

```
myproject\node_modules\firebase\auth-node\auth.js:40
      throw new Error('Failed to parse service account key file: ' + error);
      ^

Error: Failed to parse service account key file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Me\Git\eebooks\eebooks-065dd2a531ca-credentials.json'
```

I'm using the firebase npm module in a node web app. 
Is there some new authentication procedure I should be following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. 
It seems the initializeApp function was updated and requires more parameters now.

```
var config = {
        apiKey: "--",
        authDomain: "--.com",
        databaseURL: "https://--.com",
        storageBucket: "project----.appspot.com",
        };
var firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: I've got the same error and my config has 6 lines, and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a filed called 'eebooks-065dd2a531ca-credentials.json' in your project ( or folder 'C:\Users\Me\Git\eebooks\'), ENOENT means there is not that file.

Comment: There is not such a file